# Quick Tag Select

Tags: feature-request, tags

From time to time, I like to give back to the SA community and answer some questions. However, I'm not knowledgeable in everything from my site (Stack Overflow) so I tend to just search for questions related to tags that I know some things about, like `Java` or `Libgdx`.

It's a small inconvenience, but when I want to look up `Libgdx`, which is a more uncommon tag, I have to type it into the search bar.

Therefore, I've come up with a solution to make it slightly easier to get to your desired tag. Instead of just displaying a list of tags in the "Tags" tab, there should also be a panel with your 3 - 10 (depending on how many fit in one line) top tags from that site at the top of the list. This will make getting to questions of only a certain tag, that you're interested, a little easier to reach.

Comment: This already exists.